# Why Bubble sort complexity is O(n^2)?

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting, bubble-sort

As I understand, the complexity of an algorithm is a maximum number of operations performed while sorting. So, the complexity of Bubble sort should be a sum of arithmmetic progression (from 1 to n-1), not n^2. 
The following implementation counts number of comparisons:

```
public int[] sort(int[] a) {
    int operationsCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            operationsCount++;
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(operationsCount);
    return a;
}
```

The ouput for array with 10 elements is 45, so it's a sum of arithmetic progression from 1 to 9.

So why Bubble sort's complexity is n^2, not S(n-1) ?

Answer (score 8):

This is because big-O notation describes the nature of the algorithm.  The major term in the expansion `(n-1) * (n-2) / 2` is `n^2`.  And so as `n` increases all other terms become insignificant.

You are welcome to describe it more precisely, but for all intents and purposes the algorithm exhibits *behaviour* that is of the order `n^2`.  That means if you graph the time complexity against `n`, you will see a parabolic growth curve.

Comment: In case of Bubble sort the real number of operations is 2 times smaller then n^2.  
Why using approximations and not the exact number of operations? Maybe comparing some algorithms this difference will matter.  
  
And how did you get `(n-1) * (n-2) / 2` ? The sum (1 to n-1) is calculated as `(1 + (n-1))/2 * (n-1) = (n^2 - n) / 2`

Comment: Sure, you can approximate to `n^2 / 2` if you like.  But it still exhibits `n^2` growth.  That is the point.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a worst case analysis.

In the worst case, the `if (a[i] > a[j])` test will always be true, so the next 3 lines of code will be executed in each loop step. The inner loop goes from j=i+1 to n-1, so it will execute `Sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}{k}` elementary operations (where k is a constant number of operations that involve the creation of the `temp` variable, array indexing, and value copying). If you solve the summation, it gives a number of elementary operations that is equal to `k(n-i-1)`. The external loop will repeat this `k(n-i-1)` elementary operations from i=0 to i=n-1 (ie. `Sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{k(n-i-1)}`). So, again, if you solve the summation you see that the final number of elementary operations is proportional to n^2. The algorithm is quadratic in the worst case.

As you are incrementing the variable `operationsCount` before running any code in the inner loop, we can say that k (the number of elementary operations executed inside the inner loop) in our previous analysis is 1. So, solving `Sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-i-1}` gives `n^2/2 - n/2`, and substituting n with 10 gives a final result of 45, just the same result that you got by running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario:
indicates the longest running time performed by an algorithm given any input of size n

so we will consider the completely backward list for this worst-case scenario

```
int[] arr= new int[]{9,6,5,3,2};

Number of iteration or for loops required to completely sort it  = n-1 //n - number of elements in the list

1st iteration requires (n-1) swapping + 2nd iteration requires (n-2) swapping + ……….. + (n-1)th iteration requires (n-(n-1)) swapping

i.e. (n-1) + (n-2) + ……….. +1 = n/2(a+l) //sum of AP
=n/2((n-1)+1)=n^2/2
```

so big O notation = O(n^2)